# .NET Core BackgroundService Run Only Once

Tags: .net, .net-core, background-service

I am creating a .net core BackgroundService console application. The default template provides a Worker class that has ExecuteAsync() method, which is great.

My plan is to use a Windows Task Scheduler to schedule to execute the console app once a day. However, I realized the ExecuteAsync() is a continuously executing method. So my question is -- how do I execute the codes in ExecuteAsync() only once and then terminate the Worker? I might have other processes still running, so each individual process needs to run once and terminate itself.

Or is BackgroundService not the best choice for me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you're mistaken:
The [ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executeasync) of a registered [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice) is only executed once by the [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host) you are using through the `dotnet new worker` template.

The abstract class [BackgroundService](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs) is a "base class for implementing a long running [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice)".
It calls your *overridden* [ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executeasync) implementation and yields control to the `Host` when an `await` operator is encountered.
This enables the [StartAsync(CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.startasync) of another `IHostedService` to be called during startup before your `BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)` ran to completion.
Likewise, this also enables [StopAsync(CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.stopasync) of another `IHostedService` to be called during shutdown before your `BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)` is cancelled gracefully.

Be aware of the "repeat-until-your-BackgroundService-is-stopped"-loop in the `Worker Service`-Template

```cs
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{...}
```

which represents a long running service.

If your scheduled work is the only `IHostedService` in your app and/or it isn't actually a long running service - which it doesn't seem to be when executed on a daily basis - rather than deriving from `BackgroundService`, you may just implement `IHostedService` directly, add your logic to `StartAsync`, and register it via [AddHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice).

When your work is done, you want to shutdown your application host via [IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.stopapplication).
To do so, you can access `IHostApplicationLifetime` via [Constructor Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection#constructor-injection), and then call `StopApplication()` after your daily operation at the end of `StartAsync`.
The [HostBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder) which is created by [Host.CreateDefaultBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder) already adds a *Singleton* `ApplicationLifetime`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from FlashOver is correct -- `ExecuteAsync` is called once. Not repeatedly.

If you want to have something happen at a specific time in a `IHostedService`, read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) from Microsoft.

I will paste the code here in case the link rots away:

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private int executionCount = 0;
    private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Inject it as so:

```
services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
```

Now, keep in mind that if your application scales horizontally where you have more than one instance then you will have more than one timer running. This generally is not a good thing.

In cases where I need a task to run at a specific time of day I use an Azure Function set up as a CRON job.