# Start and Stop Worker Service repeatedly

Tags: c#, .net-core, background-service

There are two files in this project, `program.cs` to operate the service and `worker.cs` that contains the service logic.
Inside `program.cs`, the methods I use as following is used to operate the service:

```cs
// program.cs (partially)
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string a = client.ReceiveFrameString();  // To receive a flag from external programs to start the service
        if (bool.Parse(a))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START");
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadProc));
            t.Start(args);
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync().Wait(); // This works at the first start
            // ATTENTION! CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run() will return an error about args.Length < 0
            Console.WriteLine("DONE Start");
        }
    }
}
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
public static void ThreadProc(object obj)
{
    string[] args = ToStringArray(obj);
    while (true)
    {
        string temp = recv.ReceiveFrameString();  // To receive a flag from external programs to stop the service
        if (!bool.Parse(temp))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("STOP");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().StopAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE Stop");
            break;  // Jump out of the loop as soon as the service is stopped.
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using a while loop to create a "Start-Stop" set that contains the command to start the service and a thread to stop the service when triggered from an external source. I can observe whether the service is successfully started and stopped according to the logging output inside overwritten StartAsync and StopAsync methods in BackgroundService class like below:

```cs
// worker.cs (partially)
public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("STARTED!!");
    await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
}
public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("STOPPED!!");
    await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Now the command to start the service works at the first trigger, but the StopAsync does not work as expected while the thread is successfully called.

As an expected result, I would like the service to be able to be started and stopped repeatedly. What are the problems under that? And is there a solution for that?

#### EDIT 1

The minimal reproducible example is [located here.](https://github.com/ONLYA/Display_only/tree/master/5)

#### EDIT 2 (UPDATE)

After days of research on stack overflow and MSDN, I finally figure out a possible solution in my scenario.

At first, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63307881/13406850), I am sure that my application is not a long-run service, so I remove the "repeat-until-your-BackgroundService-is-stopped"-loop in the Worker Service Template:

```cs
// From worker.cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    // Remove the while loop
    /*while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        // await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }*/
}
```

Secondly, according to [this MSDN C# API about `RunAsync(IHost, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostingabstractionshostextensions.runasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions_RunAsync_Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHost_System_Threading_CancellationToken_), I can create a CancellationSource that can generate a CancellationToken to cancel it. Similar to [the example given in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netcore-3.1#examples), I can shut down the worker by cancelling the source. Therefore, the implementation becomes:

```cs
// From program.cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string a = client.ReceiveFrameString();  // To receive a flag from external programs to start the service
        if (bool.Parse(a))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START");
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = source.Token;
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadProc));
            t.Start(source);
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync(token);
            Console.WriteLine("DONE Start");
        }
    }
}
public static void ThreadProc(object obj)
{
    var source = obj as CancellationTokenSource;
    while (true)
    {
        string temp = recv.ReceiveFrameString();  // To receive a flag from external programs to stop the service
        if (!bool.Parse(temp))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("STOP");
            source.Cancel();
            source.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE Stop");
            break;  // Jump out of the loop as soon as the service is stopped.
        }
    }
}
```

However, this solution is not applicable to the worker with the "repeat-until-your-BackgroundService-is-stopped"-loop. It seems that the CancellationToken cannot trigger the cancellation request inside ExecuteAsync in the `worker.cs`. This should be the problem now be asked: **How to start and stop the worker service with the "repeat-until-your-BackgroundService-is-stopped"-loop?**
[The original Minimal Producible Example was adjusted according to the EDIT 2 now.](https://github.com/ONLYA/Display_only/tree/master/5)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Enigmativity Please see the last edit for the minimal reproducible example.